# How do I compare elements of vectors in C++?

Tags: c++

I currently have this code:

```
std::vector<std::string> words { "apple","banana","broccoli","lettuce" };
std::vector<std::string> disliked_words { "broccoli","carrot","tomato","lettuce" };

for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
    if (words[i] == disliked_words[0] || words[i] == disliked_words[1]  || words[i] == disliked_words[2] || words[i] == disliked_words[3]  )
        words[i] = "BLEEP";
for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
    std::cout << words[i] << " ";
```

It compares the elements in the second list to see if there are similar elements in the first list, when this is the case, the word gets replaced with "BEEP". However, the if statement is very inefficient and I was wondering if anybody knew how I could optimize this.

Sorry if this is a silly question, it's my first one.

Comment: Loop inside loop...

Comment: You may like to consider using a `std::set<std::string>` for `disliked_words`.

Comment: Thanks buddy. That was indeed a stupid question.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the standard [Algorithms library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sW5Vpt

Comment: maybe `std::find_first_of`

Comment: Maybe [`std::any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur Please don't shotgun recommend, telling the user effectively "GTFO" to places that, as far as you know, will just close the question isn't helpful. It is just a waste of people's time on those sites and makes for a really poor experience for the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested loop (loop in another loop).

```
std::vector<std::string> words { "apple","banana","broccoli","lettuce" };
std::vector<std::string> disliked_words { "broccoli","carrot","tomato","lettuce" };

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
      for(unsigned int j=0;j<disliked_words.size();j++){
        if (words[i] == disliked_words[j]){
            words[i] = "BLEEP";
            break;
        }
      }
        std::cout << words[i] << " ";
    }
```

Time Complexity: O(n^2).
There's also no need to loop through the `words` vector more than once.

Comment: Thank you very much, this will do as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. But not sure if it is efficient. The best bet would probably to use regex, I would think.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

const std::vector<std::string> words { "apple","banana","broccoli","lettuce" };
const std::set<std::string> disliked_words { "broccoli","carrot","tomato","lettuce" };

int main() {
    for(const auto& word : words) {
        if(disliked_words.find(word) == disliked_words.end())
            std::cout << word << " ";
        else
            std::cout << "Bleep "; 
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Produces: `apple banana Bleep Bleep`

**Edit:** In `c++20` you could even use [std::set::contains](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/contains) and reduce the if statement to `if(!disliked_words.contains(word))`.

Comment: Thank you all so much! I thought that I wouldn't get a single reply :P

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hand-written loops, you could do the replacement with some Standard Library algorithms.

```
// lambda to search for a match in disliked_words
auto disliked = [&](const std::string &word) {
    return std::find(disliked_words.begin(), disliked_words.end(), word) != disliked_words.end();
};

// replace any matched words
std::replace_if(words.begin(), words.end(), disliked, "BLEEP");
```

I've used [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to search for a word match and [`std::replace_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) to replace elements in the container. It could be done as a one-liner but this might be more readable.

Comment: Might also want to mention std::set_difference

Comment: This was what I was looking for, I knew that there had to be a function in the STL that would solve this problem more easily.